# Potential risk from profiting forward Futures contract?

Tags: futures

Assuming I am bought gold at \$100 from spot market, and I am shorting gold December-31 futures at \$120 which is cash settled, and I earn \$20 forward premium when settle; And when gold price drop, of course I can gain from Dec-31 futures contract as it also consider a hedge, what if the Gold price pumped to \$200? At the end I will need to sell my gold at spot market to settle the futures contract losses, even there isn't any collateral damage, my basket now changed from Gold to USD as currency, if I intended to hold Gold in long term, isn't this would defeat the purpose of risk free profit making?

Answer (score 2):

1. gold futures (COMEX, anyway) are physically settled
2. unless your PB is offering you cross-margining between
   spot and futures, you have a lot of MTM / margin risk on the trade. This is not "risk free profit making". There is no such thing. If you think there is, you are overlooking something (latency, execution risk, operational risk, etc.)
3. if your goal is to "hold gold in long term", why are you trading calendars?!